# .htaccess rewrite "?p=hello-world" to "/hello-world"

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I have a blog site hosted on Hostinger, and I am using `.htaccess` to rewrite some URLs.
However, I have been trying to rewrite my blog posts URLs from `http://localhost/article.php?p=hello-world` to `http://localhost/article/hello-world` but no success. I found some other Stackoverflow references but they did not solve my issue.

Here is my current .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^config\.php - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|sql|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh|svn|7z|zip|rar|gz|tar)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Please help me understand what is needed to be added and where.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but nowhere in that configuration file you posted are any traces of an attempt to implement the rewriting you ask for. How do you expect us to help with your implementation if you do not post your attempt?

Comment: It sounds like you have the concept of rewrite rules backwards.  You would normally rewrite `/article/hello-world` such that is actually handled by `/article.php?p=hello-world`.  That enables the simpler URL without parameters to work so that you can show it to users while still using `articles.php` behind the scenes in a way that is not visible to users.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller May I see an example please?

Comment: For example `RewriteRule /article/hello-world /article.php?p=hello-world [L]`